# Не позиционируются новые элементы в Masonry после AJAX запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, masonry

Как задать позиционирование новым карточкам в Masonry сетке после AJAX запроса. Есть карточки в контейнере. После нажатия на кнопку Load More новые карточки не позиционируются.
Пробовал два метода:

1. незакомментированный
2. закомментированный

   import Masonry from "masonry-layout";
   import imagesLoaded from "imagesloaded";

   export default () => {
   const msnry = new Masonry('.news-inner.grid', {
   itemSelector: '.news-inner .grid-item',
   columnWidth: '.news-inner .grid-sizer',
   gutter: '.news-inner .gutter-sizer',
   percentPosition: true,
   });

   const grid = document.querySelector('.news-inner.grid');

   imagesLoaded(grid, function () {
   msnry.options.itemSelector = '.news-inner .grid-item';

   ```
    const items = grid.querySelectorAll('.news-inner .grid-item');

    msnry.reloadItems(items); // This reload the masonry layout after the first call
    msnry.layout(); // This restrain the overlapping on the first call
   ```

   });

   // function masonryUpdate() {
   //   setTimeout(function () {
   //     // masonryInstance.masonry();
   //     msnry.reloadItems();
   //   }, 500);
   // }

   // document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', masonryUpdate);
   };

Answer (score 0):

Пофиксил повтроной инициализацией Masonry в ответе сервера после AJAX запроса.
Получилось, что в одном компоненте сделал первичную инициализацию Masonry.
А в другом, где делается запрос делаю в ответе повторную инициализацию Masonry и использую imagesLoaded.

Использовал вместе с Masonry:

> [Axios](https://axios-http.com/)

> [imagesLoaded](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/)

Код:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import Masonry from 'masonry-layout';
import imagesLoaded from 'imagesloaded';

export default () => {
  const posts_container = document.querySelector('.post-inner');
  const loadMoreBtn = document.querySelector('#ajax_load_posts');

  loadMoreBtn.style.display = 'none';

  // console.log('posts_container:', posts_container);

  let data = new FormData();

  data.append('action', 'loadmore');
  data.append('query', true_posts);
  data.append('page', current_page);
  data.append('post_type', post_type);

  // console.log('data:', data);

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
  }).then((response) => {
    if (response.data) {
      // posts_container.append(data.data); // insert new posts
      posts_container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', response.data);
      current_page++;

      initMasonryGrid();

      function initMasonryGrid() {
        const grid = document.querySelector('.masonry-grid');

        const msnry = new Masonry(grid, {
          itemSelector: '.masonry-grid .grid-item',
          columnWidth: '.masonry-grid .grid-sizer',
          gutter: '.masonry-grid .gutter-sizer',
          percentPosition: true,
        });

        imagesLoaded(grid, () => {
          msnry.options.itemSelector = '.news-inner .grid-item';

          const items = grid.querySelectorAll('.news-inner .grid-item');

          msnry.reloadItems(items); // This reload the masonry layout after the first call
          msnry.layout(); // This restrain the overlapping on the first call
        });
      }
      
      if (current_page != max_pages) {
        loadMoreBtn.style.display = 'flex';
      }

      return data;
    } else {
      loadMoreBtn.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
    }
    // preloader.style.display = 'none';
  });
};
```